# High-rep hammers hamper high-rep humans

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

Sorry about the silly title - it just sort of happened that way and then I couldn't resist the alliteration.

---

[Tag badges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) are awarded when you earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers with a specific tag.  A "privilege" gained due to this is the ability to use a close-vote hammer.  This means that users with this badge may simply close questions at will without the need for up to 4 more votes from other users.  Of course moderators also have this ability automatically for all questions.  I believe this ability is colloquially known as a "hammer".

This privilege is great when it is clear the question should be closed.  However there have been situations where I have wanted to cast a close vote but felt that I wanted other user's votes as well before the question is closed.  In other words, it can be argued that these hammers give dictatorial rights to high-rep users (and mods) while effectively taking away democratic rights.

The end-result of this gives hammer-wielders a choice:

1. Don't close-vote at all
2. Use close-vote hammer even if you want other users input, then question whether you really did the right thing (potentially scaring off new users)
3. Wait for other users' close-votes and then catch the 4th or 5th close-vote - in reality I usually end up missing this window and so this is basically option 1.

I don't really have any great suggestions for how to deal with this.  I guess one possibility is a [feature-request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to allow a choice of vote-or-hammer, but somehow that seems unlikely to fly.

---

There is [related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer) in meta.SE, but I think PPCG.SE is a bit special in this regard in that the majority of questions are tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), and so users earn this hammer sooner.

Comment: I think the problem is how we think of closing questions. On hold should mean that the question isn't ready for posting, not that it's inherently flawed.

Answer (score 12):

First and foremost, from [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590):

> The rules are:
>
> - You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

That means your close votes for other reasons (*off topic*, *too broad*, etc.) are still not binding, and you can cast them as usual.

Regarding the dupe hammer, you don't have a duplicate *vote* anymore; don't treat it like one. If you think that a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question is a duplicate, close it. Yes, this will be binding, but it's not final. The question can just as easily be reopened if the community disagrees with you.

The principal effect of closing a question is preventing it from getting answers, and the sooner that happens, the better.

Duplicates can be pretty hard to identify, so if you found a similar question but are not convinced that its a duplicate, leave a comment and let others decide.

Comment: Thanks.  Out of interest, how does this apply to mod-hammers - are mods able cast non-hammer votes as if they were non-mod users?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma no.

Comment: No, mods cannot vote. All mod actions are automatically binding.

Comment: But at least the site engine could add a warning in the close dialog. :( I find it horrible UX to show the same dialog then perform a different action.